# PUT and DELETE on IIS7/PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, http, rest, iis, laravel

I'm having trouble making PUT and DELETE requests to my Laravel-powered API work on IIS7.

Answers to other questions have said to allow the PUT and DELETE verbs to be mapped to the ExtensionlessUrlHandler handler. This doesn't work for me, possibly because the API is PHP, and that handler doesn't send the request to PHP?

I've made it work by adding a new handler, mapping `*` to `FastCgiHandler` (the same as `.php` is mapped to). This makes PUT and DELETE requests to the API work, but means that the server is using `php-cgi.exe` to serve static content, meaning my stylesheets aren't coming through correctly.

I can't add the handler mapping *just* to the /api folder, because routing is handled via Laravel so there *isn't* an /api folder to put the web.config file into.

Request filtering is set to allow all verbs (even unlisted ones), and I don't have WebDAV installed (two other common solutions).

It may be that I have the handler situation set up incorrectly to begin with? I'm not sure; I'm no expert on IIS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to 
Handler Mappings > PHPXX_via_FastCGI > Edit (right click) > Request Restrictions > Verbs
and select "All Verbs" (or add PUT and DELETE to the list)

where `XX` is the version you're using (for example I use PHP 5.4 so it's `54`).