# Laravel passport PUT Api getting 401 Unauthorized on Window server

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have developed a application in Laravel, Vue and uploaded on window server.Everything was working fine but two days ago, PUT API is not working and getting response 401 unauthorized.This error occur only PUT API, GET and POST are working fine.

Same code is working on my localhost and another Linux server.

Refer this url to view PUT error message.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KJ-AxWa3dD-uGq1fbI5xfB8Wam8NhTdr

Refer this url for GET success response
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ioNftSOQvAgeGgPFpLTpDfu2xVont9Lf

Comment: Hi, Issue has been resolved to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181966/put-and-delete-on-iis7-php-laravel

Comment: This question is unclear and unanswerable given the available details in your question, but it sounds like you also think it is a duplicate of [PUT and DELETE on IIS7/PHP/Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181966/put-and-delete-on-iis7-php-laravel)?